# Bing API related searches

Tags: bing-api

How does one get related searches to be included in response from Bing search API?

I am trying to apply responseFilter with value RelatedSearches as per the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-web-api-v7-reference#relatedsearchanswer

Below is my code based on sample from Bing. I have added "&responseFilter=RelatedSearches" to the URL that is fetched by file_get_contents().

The error I get back is:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?responseFilter=RelatedSearches&q=iphone+case): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

Clearly I am applying it wrong. What can I change to be making it working?

```
<?php
$accessKey = 'abc123';
$endpoint = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search';
$term = 'burrito recipe';

function BingWebSearch ($url, $key, $query) {
    $headers = "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $key\r\n";
    $options = array ('http' => array (
                        'header' => $headers,
                        'method' => 'GET'));
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url . "?q=" . urlencode($query) . "&responseFilter=RelatedSearches", false, $context);
    $headers = array();
    foreach ($http_response_header as $k => $v) {
        $h = explode(":", $v, 2);
        if (isset($h[1]))
            if (preg_match("/^BingAPIs-/", $h[0]) || preg_match("/^X-MSEdge-/", $h[0]))
                $headers[trim($h[0])] = trim($h[1]);
    }
    return array($headers, $result);
}

if (strlen($accessKey) == 32) {
    print "Searching the Web for: " . $term . "\n";
    list($headers, $json) = BingWebSearch($endpoint, $accessKey, $term);
    print "\nRelevant Headers:\n\n";
    foreach ($headers as $k => $v) {
        print $k . ": " . $v . "\n";
    }
    print "\nJSON Response:\n\n";
    echo json_encode(json_decode($json), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

} else {
    print("Invalid Bing Search API subscription key!\n");
    print("Please paste yours into the source code.\n");
}
?>
```

Comment: Of course, as soon as I post the question, 5 mins later the answer becomes obvious to me and now I feel stupid. I was using the wrong pricing tier. You need to be selecting the S1 pricing tier. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/search-api/

Answer (score 0):

The "403 Forbidden" is the hint. You don't have permission to request RelatedSearches unless you are on the S1 instance as per here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/search-api/